# Will async_receive_from writes in the buffer if the ioservice is busy handling a callback?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

So, suppose I have the following callback for `async_recv_from`

```
void recv_callback(error_code&, std::size_t len) {
    socket.async_recv_from(buffer,endpoint,recv_callback);
    handle(buffer);
}
```

So, the first thing I do in the callback is request more receives, but since the ioservice is busy handling the callback, I though that maybe my buffer would not be overwritten before the callback is finished. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This depends.

It depends on the way the underlying IO operations are actually implemented. I think some OSes might actually write directly into user-space memory.

I'd always hand-off the actual buffer.

Comment: Lets assume that the OS reads data through a kernel buffer. Is it guaranteed that the user buffer won't be filled async'ly? I'm afraid not.

Comment: I would not assume this. Async is async, and if there's no OS support for async calls (completion ports, e.g.)  things _will_ be emulated using multiple threads